# (gcloud.app.deploy) The following file couldn't be read because its path

Tags: node.js, meteor, deployment, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I have been trying to deploy a Meteor JS app on Google cloud but keeps getting this error. I followed this tutorial - https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-meteor-on-google-app-engine which is really good and understandable to follow. I don't know if the error I'm getting is as a result of error in my config but to the best of my knowledge I think I've followed the tutorial religiously.

this is my config. i am working in Windows 10 environment.

```
{
  "name": "myadminapps",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "cleanup": "rmdir /s ..\\bundle\\",
    "dist": "npm run cleanup && meteor build ..\\ --directory --architecture os.linux.x86_64 --server-only",
    "predeploy": "npm run dist && copy app.yaml ..\\bundle\\ && copy Dockerfile ..\\bundle\\",
    "deploy": "npm run predeploy && (copy ..\\bundle && gcloud app deploy -q)",
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "addressparser": "^1.0.1",
    "async": "^2.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bulk-email-verifier": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

This is the error log

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Kadeoya>cd C:\Programs\contract\myadminapps

C:\Programs\contract\myadminapps>npm run deploy

> myadminapps@ predeploy C:\Programs\contract\myadminapps
> npm run dist && copy app.yaml ..\bundle\ && copy Dockerfile ..\bundle\


> myadminapps@ dist C:\Programs\contract\myadminapps
> npm run cleanup && meteor build ..\ --directory --architecture os.linux.x86_64 --server-only


> myadminapps@ cleanup C:\Programs\contract\myadminapps
> rmdir /s ..\bundle\

..\bundle\, Are you sure (Y/N)? y
        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.

> myadminapps@ deploy C:\Programs\contract\myadminapps
> npm run predeploy && (copy ..\bundle && gcloud app deploy -q)


> myadminapps@ predeploy C:\Programs\contract\myadminapps
> npm run dist && copy app.yaml ..\bundle\ && copy Dockerfile ..\bundle\


> myadminapps@ dist C:\Programs\contract\myadminapps
> npm run cleanup && meteor build ..\ --directory --architecture os.linux.x86_64 --server-only


> myadminapps@ cleanup C:\Programs\contract\myadminapps
> rmdir /s ..\bundle\

..\bundle\, Are you sure (Y/N)? y
..\bundle\programs\server\npm\NODE_M~1\meteor\FORTAW~1\NODE_M~1\JSON-S~1 - The directory is not empty.
        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.
..\bundle\.node_version.txt
..\bundle\app.yaml
..\bundle\Dockerfile
..\bundle\main.js
..\bundle\README
..\bundle\star.json
        6 file(s) copied.
Services to deploy:

descriptor:      [C:\Programs\contract\myadminapps\app.yaml]
source:          [C:\Programs\contract\myadminapps]
target project:  [rabonni-184612]
target service:  [default]
target version:  [20171121t005558]
target url:      [https://adminapps-184612.appspot.com]


Beginning deployment of service [default]...
Building and pushing image for service [default]
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) The following file couldn't be read because its path is too long:

  [C:\Programs\contract\myadminapps\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\npm\node_modules\meteor\reywood_publish-composite\node_modules\eslint-config-airbnb\node_modules\eslint-plugin-import\node_modules\eslint-import-resolver-node\node_modules\resolve\test\dotdot/*.*]

For more information on this issue and possible workarounds, please read the
following (links are specific to Node.js, but the information is generally
applicable):

* https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/issues/69
* https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#max_path-explanation-and-workarounds
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myadminapps@ deploy: `npm run predeploy && (copy ..\bundle && gcloud app deploy -q)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myadminapps@ deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Kadeoya\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-21T08_57_10_491Z-debug.log

C:\Programs\contract\myadminapps>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant line in that log is this:

`The following file couldn't be read because its path is too long:`

Which was a common issue with `npm` prior to npm v3 in windows because of nested node modules. npm v3 and up now tries to flatten the dependency graph as much as possible, which helps a lot in dealing with windows path limits.

Which version of Meteor are you using? And which version of npm are you using globally? 
Try with `meteor npm run deploy` to use the version bundled with meteor.

A quick fix which sometimes works is to copy your meteor app dir to `c:/myapp` to reduce the path length before a build.